# How to make a textview slide out of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, slide

I've just learning android for a week. I want to ask if the text view can slide in and out the screen manual.
here is my xml code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/streetName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#A0000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Duong Quang Trung"
        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

It's look like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LecsX.jpg]

And i want it to disappear, it's only appear (slide in) when i touch the screen. How did i do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ve to use swipe event in android.
visit following event:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html
go with some swipe examples in android.